# Is there a web browser for Mac OS 10.5 (x86) that can play Youtube videos?

Tags: macos, youtube

I have a core duo laptop that has Mac OS 10.5 on it. I would like to watch Youtube videos on it. Is there a web browser that runs on this operating system that can play Youtube videos?

Comment: I have tried Safari. It does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find TenFourFox. It does play Youtube videos. I was able to watch a 720p video on a core duo Macbook with it :)

Here is the download link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/tenfourfox/files/unstable/contrib/

There are binaries for both Mac OS 10.4 and Mac OS 10.5. I successfully used the Tiger version on both operating systems for watching Youtube.